# Slick Slider Syncing Multiple sliders - 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I'm using slick Slider Syncing with 3 sliders. With 2 sliders it works fine but when I try with 3 sliders with 3 classes still only 2 are working.

example » https://jsfiddle.net/rk0tuoy7/6/

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: false,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand'
});
$('.slider-x').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  fade: false,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  dots: false
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand'
});
```

```css
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css');
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css');

.slick-slide {
  background: #3a8999;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-arrow:before {
  color: black;
}

.slick-dots {
  bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #e84a69;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider slider-x">
  <div><h3>2015</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2014</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2013</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2012</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2011</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2010</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2009</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2008</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2007</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2006</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2005</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2004</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2003</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2002</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2001</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2000</h3></div>
  <div><h3>1995</h3></div>
</div>

<div class="slider slider-nav">
  <div><h3>2015</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2014</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2013</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2012</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2011</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2010</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2009</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2008</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2007</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2006</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2005</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2004</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2003</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2002</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2001</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2000</h3></div>
  <div><h3>1995</h3></div>
</div>

<div class="slider slider-for">
  <div><h3>2015</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2014</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2013</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2012</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2011</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2010</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2009</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2008</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2007</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2006</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2005</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2004</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2003</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2002</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2001</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2000</h3></div>
  <div><h3>1995</h3></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the `asNavFor` option works as a normal CSS selector. You can list several classes separated by commas:

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav,.slider-x',
});
$('.slider-x').slick({
  asNavFor: '.slider-for,.slider-nav',
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  asNavFor: '.slider-for,.slider-x',
});
```

I've removed options that have default values.

Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/b6c2ayeg/

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  arrows: false,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav,.slider-x',
});
$('.slider-x').slick({
  arrows: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for,.slider-nav',
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  arrows: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for,.slider-x',
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  dots: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  slidesToShow: 5,
});
```

```css
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css');
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css');

.slick-slide {
  background: #3a8999;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-arrow:before {
  color: black;
}

.slick-dots {
  bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #e84a69;
}

.slider {
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider slider-x">
  <div><h3>2015</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2014</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2013</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2012</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2011</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2010</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2009</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2008</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2007</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2006</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2005</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2004</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2003</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2002</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2001</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2000</h3></div>
  <div><h3>1995</h3></div>
</div>

<div class="slider slider-nav">
  <div><h3>2015</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2014</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2013</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2012</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2011</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2010</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2009</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2008</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2007</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2006</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2005</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2004</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2003</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2002</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2001</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2000</h3></div>
  <div><h3>1995</h3></div>
</div>

<div class="slider slider-for">
  <div><h3>2015</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2014</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2013</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2012</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2011</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2010</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2009</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2008</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2007</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2006</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2005</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2004</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2003</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2002</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2001</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2000</h3></div>
  <div><h3>1995</h3></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
```